# How to change the background color of selected bottom tab in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react native navigation v2 for by application. I need to change the background color of the selected bottom tab.

```
options: {
    bottomTab: {
        icon: val.icon,
        text: val.text,
        textColor: getColorTheme("SECONDARY", "LIGHT"),
        selectedTextColor: getColorTheme("ORANGE", "LIGHT"),
        selectedIconColor: getColorTheme("ORANGE", "LIGHT"),
        fontFamily: FONTFAMILY.SEMIBOLD,
        fontSize: FONTSIZE.FONT_12,
        selectedFontSize: FONTSIZE.FONT_12,
        selectedBackgroundColor:'red'
    }
}
```

Comment: You Should consider switching off to v5 because v2 seems to be very old.

Comment: @yesIamFaded  is it possible to change the background color of active tab in v5? v2 it cannot be done?

Comment: yes you can definitly change the tab colors to your needs in v5

Comment: I am also facing same issue, did you got solution ?

Answer (score -2):

as @yeslamFaded it could be a good idea to use a newer version of react-navigation.

if you want to change the background color of the selected tab you can use the `activeBackgroundColor` prop of `tabBarOptions` when you are creating the bottom tab navigator

for instance :

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeBackgroundColor: 'tomato',
    },
  }
);
```

All the properties are available in the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/bottom-tab-navigator/#bottomtabnavigatorconfig)

Comment: Provided solution from reactnavigation, question for react-native-navigation